# Parsing XMLs and then modifying output

Tags: python, regex

I made a python script that parses through xml output of a test result and then prints the testsuite name, the testcases within it and with the pass and fail. Below is an example: the percentage tells you the passing percent for the testcases in the suite. the number 65 and 85 are runtimes. If a test fails I have to rerun that specific test which in turn makes a new XML file. What I am looking to do is to gather all the results by parsing through all the XMLs. If a test fails 10 times. then it will print that beside it with all of its runtime.

> TestSuite 0%
>
> Testcase1  65 FAIL
>
> Testcase2  86  FAIL

currently the output looks like this

> TestSuite 0%
>
> > Testcase1  65 FAIL
> >
> > Testcase2  86  FAIL
>
> TestSuite1 50%
>
> > Testcase5 43 FAIL
> >
> > Testcase6 78 PASS
>
> TestSuite 50%
>
> > Testcase1  65 FAIL
> >
> > Testcase2  87  FAIL

Notice how "TestSuite" is repeated twice as its seen in 2 XMLs. Ideally what i would like is instead of it printing all the same testcases again and again, I would like the script to print 1 Testsuite and then it specifies how many times each test case passed or failed. Currently i output all the results in a log file and i was using regex to parse out these details but I am stuck and dont know what to do.

EDIT::

```
import  re
import collections

testsuites=[]
theFile=open('output.log','r')
FILE=theFile.readlines()
testname=[]
Entire_line=[]
for line in FILE:
   searchObj=re.search('^[A-Z].*$',line)
   searchObj_1=re.search('^([a-z].*) (.*?) (.*)',line)
   searchObj_2=re.search('^[a-z].*',line)
   if searchObj:
      testsuites.append(searchObj.group())
    if searchObj_1:
      testname.append(searchObj_1.group(1))
    if searchObj_2:
      Entire_line.append(searchObj_2.group())
      print searchObj_2.group()

Entire_line=sorted(Entire_line)
print testname

print Entire_line
```

The Entire line basically prints the entire testcase in order and sorts them but doesnt count them and I just got stuck there.. Entire Lines Output:

```
testcase1 45 FAIL
testcase1 54 PASS
testcase2 66 FAIL
testcase2 77 PASS
testcase3 88 PASS
testcase4 34 PASS
```

What I want to know is that testcase1 failed once but passed the 2nd time. it ran twice. Hope this clears the air.

Comment: is 50% for last TestSuite correct?

Comment: please add some problematic code of what you are doing, not just results.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do here is use dictionaries, lists, and tuples so you end up with a structure that looks like the following:

```
{
    "TestSuite": 
        {
            "Testcase1": [(65, False), (65, False)],
            "Testcase2": [(86, False), (87, False)],
        },
    "TestSuite1":
        {
            "Testcase5": [(43, False)],
            "Testcase6": [(78, True)]
        }
}
```

After inserting results into this, you would iterate through the test suite dictionary and the test case dictionary, printing results after summing the list contents as needed.

I am on a tablet, otherwise I would write a snippet for how to create/manipulate this, but I hope the example gets some wheels turning.